# How to make an api call before component render in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, use-effect

```
  export default function Dashboard(){
      useEffect(() => {
          setTimeout(()=>console.log("API Call Completed"),5000)
      },[])

      return(
          <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
          </div>
      )
}
```

I want "API Call Completed"  to be printed on console before Dashboard is printed on the page(or before return). But the msg gets printed on console 5 secs "Dashboard" appears on the page. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can't, the timeout only _starts_ when the component is rendered (the function is called). You'd have to add some state that you can update in the callback so that it just renders null until that has finished.

Comment: So it's impossible to achieve what I need?

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem. Why do you want to delay the rendering of your component?

Comment: I need to dispatch a loadUser() function and check if there exits an user with the token(stored in localStorage) and then set the redux store isAuthenticated field as false. So the component shouldn't render before the isAuthenticated field is updated

Comment: No, it's not exactly impossible, and I suggested one way to deal with it in my first comment. You can't block rendering, but you can render nothing until later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Rendering is designed to be non-blocking.

There is no way to have it wait for something asynchronous to complete.

---

Generally the approach would be to have an initial state and then update the state from the API call's callback.

The render function can then, for example, detect the initial state and render a loading spinner.